# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus, on-hold

Yesterday, I asked this question [Replace Markdown-like links with HTML links in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078367/replace-markdown-like-links-with-html-links-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment63613688_38078367).

This was put on hold

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be 
>   too long for this format.

In my opinion, there are basically two answers now:

1. Use PHP parsedown library
2. Or use `preg_replace` with some special
   syntax

Therefore, I do not think that there are either *too many possible answers*, or that *good answers would be too long for this format*.

My original question was, extremely simplified,

> "How to convert string A to string B with PHP".

Would it improve the question if I would ask

> "How to convert string A to string B with `preg_replace`?"

I do not think that this would improve the question, since I did not know that you can do it with `preg_replace` when I asked the question. I also found it quite useful to get a hint to use the PHP parsedown library.

---

To summarize, my question is, why was this put on hold? Are there so many other possible answers which I am not aware of? And what would you recommend me to do? Should I delete the question now, or should I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a terrible question as far as questions go; you've pretty clearly stated what your input is, and what want the output to be. But it didn't occur to you to let folks know how far you've worked through the problem, which is necessary to set the scope and tone of the answers folks will write.

If you're lost at what functions in the PHP standard library could be used to accomplish it, you're *probably* not ready to ask the question yet until you've gone through the more promising search results for "replace strings with PHP" and tried a few things.

Once you've gotten *that* far, then it's a question of scoping the correct expression to do the replacement, and then wondering about what edge use cases might break your code and how to code defensively around that. That's (from what I can tell) what you really needed, and while you got some great answers - it didn't occur to either author to explain how the matching worked since you didn't indicate a need to learn that, so you'll probably need to ask again if you confront a similar problem.

If you do enough tinkering on your own to give people a pretty good idea of what you really need to learn - they'll teach, and the value of not only the question but also the answers it receives will improve immensely.

There's a dozen different ways to approach the problem as you stated it, which is why folks put it on hold. A better question would be *here's what I have, here's what it's giving me, please teach me what I need to know in order to make it give me (x)*.

There'd still be multiple ways to do it (as is true for most things), but the answers would definitely be more specific, informative and narrowly-scoped.

Answer (score 10):

The question looks like one of the hundreds of 'gimmethecodez' questions which get closed each day. It would already be a lot better if you included *what* you tried - even if `str_replace` isn't the best tool for these tasks. People will always come up with good alternatives, like the accepted answer.

Comment: It was not possible for me to give a minimal working example with `str_replace` because as far as I know you cannot extract something and reinsert it somewhere else. But you are right, maybe if I would have done more research, I would have found preg_replace and would be able to construct the necessary pattern. Would you recommend that I delete the question?

Comment: @Adam if you could provide a *working* example, you wouldn't have to ask the question. Just show what you tried, and where it fails to meet the requirement. Note that you can't delete the question - it has an upvoted and accepted answer.